# Will installing GCC 7.1 include std::is_base_of_v in the standard library?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

I've got the GCC 5 package installed on an Ubuntu 16 machine, and I'd like to compile some code that uses the newer std::is_base_of_v and other similar "using" aliases called for in the standard library by the C++17 standard. GCC is big and I've never installed a compiler before, so I'd like to know before I begin if the standard library will be upgraded too. I'd also like to make sure that clang compilation works. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What makes you doubt so?

Comment: No need to upgrade your compiler. Just try to compile your test program using `-std=c++1z`

Comment: Why not try it out on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iPlZxsrZw5QbTOCL)?

Comment: @erenon just adding -std=c++1z causes error: ‘is_base_of_v’ is not a member of ‘std’

Answer (score 4):

Here's the GCC standard library status page:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z

The symbol you are looking for was introduced by [P0006R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0006r0.html). The status page above shows, it is implemented in GCC 7. You'll need that version.